# Iterating through spark dataframe and concatente two columns for each row

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am Iterating through spark datframe and I want to concatenate two columns for each row.

```
df.collect().foreach{
      row =>
        val x = row.toSeq
        println(x)
        println(x(0))
        val y = "row(1)+row(2)"
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val dataFrame = sc.parallelize(Seq(("one", 2.0),("two", 1.5),("three", 8.0))).toDF("id", "value")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat
val dfToList = dataFrame.withColumn("concat" , concat($"id",$"value")).drop("id").drop("value").collect()
println(dfToList)
```

This gives

```
dataFrame: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, value: double]
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat
dfToList: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([one2.0], [two1.5], [three8.0])
```

Is this what are looking for ?

Comment: No , It is like when u will do witcolumn on dataframe we concat for whole row of for that column , I want to concat it on current record ,Thats why i am iterating through dataframe

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit. May be a sample input output in text would help in the question